# Register(/bind/match) a device with a driver

Tags: linux, usb, driver, bind, match

I am writing a usb driver (for a gamepad) on linux, and when I plug it in, ti loads usbhid. How can I make it so it loads my driver (gp_driver)?
I did the unbind usbhid and bind to my driver trick, but I don't want to do it every single time.

Should I have my driver already loaded?
Should I code something in my driver?
I have the vendor and product id in my driver..

thanks

Comment: This has been not relevant for me for a long time now. I am not sure which one to choose as accepted answer, but it would make sense to have a way to signify that this is not my choice anymore. Does that make sense? Thank you to all the people that answered here! :)

Answer (score 4):

You will want to create a udev rule for your device, which can take care of creating your device file, setting permissions on the device file, and loading relevant drivers.

### Resources

- http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html
- http://www.redhat.com/magazine/002dec04/features/udev/

### Example

Taken from: http://plugcomputer.org/plugwiki/index.php/Load_Serial_Drivers_Automatically_Using_udev

```
# if no driver has claimed the interface yet, load ftdi_sio
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_interface", \
        ATTRS{idVendor}=="9e88", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9e8f", \
        DRIVER=="", \
        RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -b ftdi_sio"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Binding** a (in your case HID-) device to a specific driver is not a trivial task and depends on the **kernel version** you are using:

### Kernel < 4.16

Before kernel 4.16 you had to edit and recompile `drivers/hid/hid-core.c` since this file contained a list of devices which should not be not handled by `hid-generic` (`hid_have_special_driver` struct), you can see an example of how this was done here:
https://github.com/atar-axis/xpadneo/blob/master/misc/kernel_patches/0002-hid_generic_claims_devices.patch

### Kernel >= 4.16

Starting with Kernel 4.16 the list was removed and `hid-generic` checks if any of the other drivers wants the device, if so - then `hid-generic` steps back and does not claim the device.
The related patch is: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/e04a0442d33b8cf183bba38646447b891bb02123#diff-88d50bd989bbdf3bbd2f3c5dcd4edcb9

### Workaround (works always)

You can always use an udev-rule (e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-xpadneo.rules`), either before 4.16 or whenever there is more than one specialized driver in your system:

```
# unbind the device from hid-generic on kernel < 4.16
# and bind it to the specialized driver (xpadneo in this case)
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="0005:045E:02FD.*|0005:045E:02E0.*", SUBSYSTEM=="hid",\
RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo $kernel > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/unbind'", \
RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo $kernel > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/xpadneo/bind'"

# unbind the device from another specialized driver which came first
# and bind it to xpadneo
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="0005:045E:02FD.*|0005:045E:02E0.*", SUBSYSTEM=="hid",\
RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo $kernel > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/microsoft/unbind'", \
RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo $kernel > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/xpadneo/bind'"
```

**Notes**

- Instead of `bash` you should maybe use `sh`
- I don't remember when `bind` and `unbind` where added, but it quite a while ago.

---

You can read a bit more about **loading**, **binding** and **registration** of (HID-) drivers here:

- http://0x0001.de/linux-driver-loading-registration-and-binding/
- https://github.com/atar-axis/xpadneo/issues/33

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7353) article, you need to have:

1. A pointer to the module owner of your driver
2. The name of the USB driver
3. A list of the USB IDs this driver should provide
4. A probe() function
5. A disconnect() function

Now, I suspect, because it is loading the standard driver, you may not have either 3, 4, or maybe you haven't registered the driver with the USB subsystem at all.

I've never written a USB driver before (only hacked char/mem.c), but this info might come in handy.